# any situation where az login using Service principal works even after secret expiry?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-service-principal, azure-secrets

I have been recently added to an Azure subscription. They shared me Service principal details.. which included Application(Client) ID, tenant ID, client secret. I was able to log in successfully.  But, When I checked the secret details, it's expired in the month of January 2021. Is there any situation where the Service principal works even after secret expiry?

Answer (score 0):

No, It doesn't authenticate with an expired client secret and will result in `AADSTS7000222` error.

[image]

I tested the same on **`Bash and Powershell (Terraform Authentication with SP)`** using the above shown expired secret, Both gave me the expected results as shown below:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** If You are still seeing the same response , try deleting that secret and create a new one with custom expiry date of 1 day and check if you can successfully login using the new expired secret. If you can with the new expired secret as well , then Please create a support request to Azure from Portal (Help+Support) for assisted guidance.

Comment: thanks for the response. But, I do know this. Unfortunately, I don't have permission to try this with the client's subscription. But, I have already tried what you mentioned in my personal subscription and I couldn't reproduce the issue. I probably this is a Bug in Azure. I'll raise a support request and notify them